# Can't remove or add directories

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, storage

Using the web interface I can't remove or add directories, it says I need to contact the admin to get permissions, I am admin and have all the permissions.

Any ideas why Google Cloud Platform [Storage] is suddenly messing me around?

Answer (score 1):

Seems GCP moved the permissions, fixed
IAM Admin -> Manage resources - reset the owner (even if it's already set)